# Devise current_user is nil before logging out

Tags: devise, rails-api, ruby-on-rails-5

I am working on a Rails 5 api project is running on Ruby 2.3.0 and Rails 5.0.0.alpha

I created SessionsController class that overrided Devise::SessionsController
The sign_in method as below

```
# POST /resource/sign_in
  def create
    # Devise code
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)

    # add more code
    user = User.find_for_database_authentication(email: user_params[:email])
    return invalid_login_attempt unless user
    return invalid_login_attempt unless user.valid_password?(user_params[:password])

    # reset json token when user request new session
    @token = JsonWebToken.encode(user, user.password)
    user.json_token = @token
    user.save!
    sign_in(resource_name, user)
    @message = I18n.t 'devise.sessions.signed_in'
    yield resource if block_given?

    render 'users/token'
  end
```

the sign out method as

```
# DELETE /resource/sign_out
def destroy
    # current_user is nil when went to here
    sign_out(resource_name)  
    @message = I18n.t'devise.sessions.signed_out'
    yield if block_given?
    render 'users/logout'
end
```

Before i have run the line

```
 sign_out(resource_name)
```

The value of current_user is nil

I do not know the reason.
My understanding is the value must not be nil and its value is user had logged in

How can i fix this?

Thanks